# How to filter array of objects between StartTime and EndTime timestamp and get match record

Tags: javascript

I have a time startTime 3:30 pm endTime 8:00 pm and I have second object startTime 5:30 to 6:45 this is match record because this is under 3:30 pm endTime 8:00 pm. So how we can match in javascript

```
{"entries":[{"memberId":"5bd06f45607ed03804018267","startTime":1574719200000,"endTime":1574735400000,"description":"Description","issue":"ZFJ-25","issueType":null,"issuePriority":null,"issueStatus":null,"issueSummary":"isues tect","projectKey":"ZFJ","projectName":"ZFJ","worklogId":"10299","epicKey":null,"accountKey":null,"componentKey":[],"fixVersion":null,"subTask":[],"sprint":null,"issueReporter":null,"role":null,"planned":false,"locked":true,"approvalId":"5bd06f45607ed0380401826720193023","timeSpent":"16200","mirhaiTask":null,"clientKey":"56583e1e-00d6-3794-aa29-408e43ec2bff","id":"5bd06f45607ed038040182671574836779805"},{"memberId":"5bd06f45607ed03804018267","startTime":1574725545000,"endTime":1574730045000,"description":"Description","issue":"ZFJ-24","issueType":null,"issuePriority":null,"issueStatus":null,"issueSummary":"some issue","projectKey":"ZFJ","projectName":"ZFJ","worklogId":"10298","epicKey":null,"accountKey":null,"componentKey":[],"fixVersion":null,"subTask":[],"sprint":null,"issueReporter":null,"role":null,"planned":false,"locked":true,"approvalId":"5bd06f45607ed0380401826720193023","timeSpent":"4500","mirhaiTask":null,"clientKey":"56583e1e-00d6-3794-aa29-408e43ec2bff","id":"5bd06f45607ed038040182671574836752275"},{"memberId":"5bd06f45607ed03804018267","startTime":1574736300000,"endTime":1574747100000,"description":"mqbsqnm","issue":"ZFJ-32","issueType":null,"issuePriority":null,"issueStatus":null,"issueSummary":"abcd","projectKey":"ZFJ","projectName":"ZFJ","worklogId":"10303","epicKey":null,"accountKey":null,"componentKey":[],"fixVersion":null,"subTask":[],"sprint":null,"issueReporter":null,"role":null,"planned":false,"locked":true,"approvalId":"5bd06f45607ed0380401826720193023","timeSpent":"10800","mirhaiTask":null,"clientKey":"56583e1e-00d6-3794-aa29-408e43ec2bff","id":"5bd06f45607ed038040182671575023958801"},{"memberId":"5bd06f45607ed03804018267","startTime":1574756100000,"endTime":1574766900000,"description":"dss","issue":"ZFJ-30","issueType":null,"issuePriority":null,"issueStatus":null,"issueSummary":"HI","projectKey":"ZFJ","projectName":"ZFJ","worklogId":"10305","epicKey":null,"accountKey":null,"componentKey":[],"fixVersion":null,"subTask":[],"sprint":null,"issueReporter":null,"role":null,"planned":false,"locked":true,"approvalId":null,"timeSpent":"10800","mirhaiTask":null,"clientKey":"56583e1e-00d6-3794-aa29-408e43ec2bff","id":"5bd06f45607ed038040182671575189847753"}],"memberId":"5bd06f45607ed03804018267","totalHours":11,"numIssues":4,"status":"APPROVED"}
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q4m5y7  i have only one array  and we need to match object 0 > 1 ,0 > 2 , 1 > 2 ,0>3 , 1>3 ,2> 3 like this

Answer (score 2):

Use the [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var startTime = 1575158418000;
var endTime = 1575244758000;

var entries = [
  {
    startTime: 1575190818000,
    endTime: 1575212418000
  },
  {
    startTime: 1575277218000,
    endTime: 1575284418000
  }
];

var matchingEntries = entries.filter(entry =>
  entry.startTime >= startTime && entry.endTime <= endTime);
```

**Edit:**

I think this is closer to what the poster actually needed. Here we go through the entries array and return items that have another item (= item with different identifier, in this case `workLogId`) overlapping with their start and end dates. (The `matches()` function logic isn't finished.)

```
var entries = [
  {
    workLogId: 1,
    startTime: 1575208808000,
    endTime: 1575216008000
  },
  {
    workLogId: 2,
    startTime: 1575205208000,
    endTime: 1575223208000
  },
  {
    workLogId: 3,
    startTime: 1575277218000,
    endTime: 1575284418000
  }
];

var matches = (entry1, entry2) =>
 entry1.startTime >= entry2.startTime && entry1.endTime <= entry2.endTime ||
 entry2.startTime >= entry1.startTime && entry2.endTime <= entry1.endTime
 // todo: more conditions

var matchingEntries = entries.filter(entry =>
  entries.filter(e => e.workLogId !== entry.workLogId).some(e => matches(e, entry)));
```

Comment: var startTime = 1575158418000;
var endTime = 1575244758000;   ? this is not right  i need check who is the match entry in a array each value start or end Time   example https://prnt.sc/q4m5y7

Comment: Sorry, I understood the question wrong - I added an edit to my answer, is it any help?

Comment: var matchingEntries = entries.filter(entry =>
  entries.filter(e => e.workLogId !== entry.workLogId).some(e => matches(e, entry))) ;             console.log(matchingEntries)   have you check at yourself    ?because blank arrary found ?